# mysql partitioning

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I would like to partition by a column name YEAR and column name MONTH.
It seemed that it would be nice to use LIST for YEAR and SUB PARTITION by MONTH in another list.

What would be the syntax for the subpartition part?

Is it possible to subpartition a list with another list?

Or should I use a different partitioning scheme?

Comment: how many records do you expect to have ?

Answer (score 0):

The subpartition syntax is in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html).

No, you can't subpartition a LIST with another LIST. You may partition by LIST, but you must subpartition by HASH or KEY.